# inserting variable in jQuery statement

Tags: jquery, variables

This might be a simple question, but I got confused here.

```
var videoSrc = "video/sample.mp4";
$('.abc').append('<video width="650" height="300" controls="controls"> <source src= "' 
+ videoSrc 
+ 'type="video/mp4" id="myVideo"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>'     
);
});
```

I am trying to insert the value of the variable videoSrc in the src attribute. It does not work like this.

The following code works fine:

```
$('.abc').append('<video width="650" height="300" controls="controls"> <source src="videos/sample2.mp4" '
+'type="video/mp4" id="myVideo"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>'      
);
```

But I have to insert the value of src attribute dynamically.

Help me to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked:

```
var videoSrc = "video/sample.mp4";
$('.abc').append('<video width="650" height="300" controls="controls"> <source src= " ' 
+ vidSrc 
+ ' " type="video/mp4" id="myVideo"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>'     
);
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't got a closing quote for your `src` attribute, and as @Luuk van Egeraat points out, you have a superfluous "});" at the end.

```
var videoSrc = "video/sample.mp4";
$('.abc').append('<video width="650" height="300" controls="controls"> <source src= "' 
+ videoSrc 
+ 'type="video/mp4" id="myVideo"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>'     
);
```

becomes

```
var videoSrc = "video/sample.mp4";
$('.abc').append('<video width="650" height="300" controls="controls"> <source src= "' 
+ videoSrc 
+ '" type="video/mp4" id="myVideo"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>'     
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some syntax errors, [here is a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/Luuk/NeugE/).

```
var videoSrc = "video/sample.mp4";

$('.abc').append('<video width="650" height="300" controls="controls"><source src= "' + videoSrc + '" type="video/mp4" id="myVideo"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>');​
```

Comment: The code is valid, the file, however, is not there, so nothing will play.

Comment: Hi Luuk, ya I know what you saying. Thanks for the quick help.